# In R only keep values that appear for at least 3 years, at least 10 times per year

Tags: python, r, conditional-statements

Please see a general sample of my dataset below. I only want to keep count data from IDs that appear for at least 3 years, with at least 10 appearances during each of those years. So, here, I only want the data from ID 'a', and I want to remove the data with the ID of 'b' and 'c.'

I have some basic/general knowledge of r, python, and excel. Any way to do this using any of those three languages would be great. I guess r would be preferred. Thank you.

```
ID  year    count
a   2001    2
b   2001    3
a   2001    2
a   2001    1
a   2001    4 
a   2001    0
a   2001    1
a   2001    3
a   2001    2
b   2001    3
b   2001    4
a   2001    5
b   2001    2
c   2001    3
a   2001    5
a   2001    1
c   2001    1
c   2002    2
a   2002    1
b   2002    2
c   2002    3
a   2002    2
a   2002    1
a   2002    3
a   2002    4
a   2002    3
a   2002    2
b   2002    4
b   2002    2
a   2002    1
b   2002    1
c   2002    2
a   2002    3
a   2002    4
a   2002    5
c   2002    2
a   2003    2
a   2003    1
a   2003    2
a   2003    4
c   2003    3
a   2003    2
a   2003    1
b   2003    3
a   2003    5
a   2003    3
a   2003    2
a   2003    1
a   2003    3
a   2003    2
c   2003    2
b   2003    2
b   2003    1
b   2003    4
c   2003    3
```

Comment: So what do you have so far?

Comment: Hey @hminutu's Show us ds what you've accomplished already.

Comment: Is it correct that `count` has nothing to do with deciding?  Just an ID appeared at least 10 times in each of three years?

Comment: I honestly don't have anything yet. I think there should be if-statements or something. A first if-statement for the 3 year conditional, then another if-statement for the 10 appearances conditional.

Comment: I just want the data in `count` to be carried over with its respective ID.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n_distinct(year) >= 3) %>% group_by(ID, year) %>% filter(n() >= 10)`

Answer (score 2):

In R you could use

```
GoodIDs = names(which(rowSums(table(df$ID, df$year) >= 10) >=3))
df[df$ID %in% GoodIDs,]
```

**The gory Details**

Just making a table of how many times each year-id combination occurred helps a lot.

```
table(df$ID, df$year)
    2001 2002 2003
  a   11   11   12
  b    4    4    4
  c    2    4    3
```

Now *we* see the answer (only id=a is wanted),  but we want to push that through to get the full answer.  Next step, test which entries in the table are at least 10.

```
table(df$ID, df$year) >= 10
     2001  2002  2003
  a  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  b FALSE FALSE FALSE
  c FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now we want to count how many years had true for each id. Using the fact that TRUE will be treated as 1 and FALSE will be treated as 0, we can just add across the rows.

```
rowSums(table(df$ID, df$year) >= 10)
a b c 
3 0 0
```

Now we want to test which of these was at least 3

```
which(rowSums(table(df$ID, df$year) >= 10) >=3)
a 
1
```

Now get which ID's were selected

```
names(which(rowSums(table(df$ID, df$year) >= 10) >=3))
[1] "a"
```

We store that in GoodIDs and then extract all of the rows with the selected IDs.

```
df[df$ID %in% GoodIDs,]
<output omitted>
```

Comment: This looks good...! Could you explain how it works..? Or could anyone else? It seems like it worked, but I'd really like to know more about how it does it. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I'm working through this and I think I see how it works. I forgot a key word in my original post though... I want it to be 3 consecutive years. Does this do that..? It doesn't seem like it does, but I could be wrong. Is there something I could add to make it consecutive?

Comment: This does not require years to be consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

Python Pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read the CSV file into a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_table('foo.csv', sep='\s+')
```

Group by ID and year, select only those years and IDs that have the total count of at least 10:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','year']).sum()
df2 = df1[df1 >= 10].dropna()
```

Eliminate all variables that have fewer than 3 years:

```
df3 = df2.reset_index().groupby('ID').count()['count']
df3[df3 >= 3].index.values
```

Result:

```
#array(['a'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This looks great and I really appreciate your effort to explain this thoroughly.... what exactly is python pandas though? Thank you.

Comment: Pandas is a library to handle datasets. It's used a lot in data processing

Answer (score 0):

There have already solutions being proposed using [base R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44423561/3817004), [the `dplyr` package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423439/in-r-only-keep-values-that-appear-for-at-least-3-years-at-least-10-times-per-ye#comment75845421_44423439), and [Python Panda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44423733/3817004). For the sake of completeness, I would like to suggest an R solution using the `data.table` package which has gained reputation for fast aggregation of large data, fast ordered joins, etc.

The OP wants *to keep count data from IDs that appear for at least 3 years, with at least 10 appearances during each of those years*.

So, it is necessary to identify the ID's whose data should be kept and the to filter the data set accordingly. To identify the IDs which comply with the requirements, it is important to first test which years fulfill the 10 appearances conditional for each ID and then to count the number of years per ID.

With `data.table` this can be combined in one line:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[DF[, .N, .(ID, year)][N >= 10L, .N, ID][N >= 3L, .(ID)], on = "ID"]
```

#### Explanation

1. setDT(DF) coerces the data.frame to class `data.table`.
2. `DF[, .N, .(ID, year)]` counts the number of appearances grouped by ID and year.
3. The next operation `[N >= 10L, .N, ID]` is *chained*, i.e. it takes the result of the previous step as input. It counts the number of years for each ID which fulfill the 10 appearances conditional.
4. `[N >= 3L, .(ID)]` checks for the 3 year conditional and returns a `data.table` consisting only of one column with the selected IDs.
5. The final filter operation of the full data set is implemented as a *right join* with the selected IDs. It returns only those rows of the full data set where the ID matches one of the selected IDs. In the join operation `setDT(DF)[DF[...], on = "ID"]`, the `on = "ID"` parameter tells `data.table` in which column to look for matches.

#### Data

I have added a few more rows of data for ID "b" in 2003 to cover also the case that one ID fulfills the 10 appearances conditional but only for one year.

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "b", "c", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", 
"a", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"c"), year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L
), count = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L)), .Names = c("ID", "year", "count"), row.names = c(NA, -61L
), class = "data.frame", index = structure(integer(0), "`__ID`" = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 28L, 29L, 
31L, 44L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 14L, 17L, 
18L, 21L, 32L, 36L, 41L, 51L, 61L)))
```